# How to remove multiple objects in batch call using their IDs?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

How can I remove multiple objects in batch call using their IDs ?

I tried this

```
EntityManager em = ...
em.getTransaction().begin();
try
{
    for (Visitor obj : map.keySet())
    {
        Visitor fake = em.getReference(Visitor.class, obj.getId());
        em.remove(fake);
    }

    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I see `DELETE` statements in log file but them it throws

```
<openjpa-2.1.1-r422266:1148538 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: Optimistic locking errors were detected when flushing to the data store.  The following objects may have been concurrently modified in another transaction: [com.reporting.data.Visitor-53043]
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:593)
    at com.reporting.ui.DBUtil.saveAnswers(DBUtil.java:311)
```

I have single thread.

*Update:*

I also tried

```
for (Visitor obj : map.keySet())
    em.remove(obj);
```

But it's slow because on every iteration it sends `SELECT` to a server. I assume OpenJPA does it to reattach object to context.

Comment: It's strange that `HibernateTemplate` has `deleteAll()` but EntityManager has no equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After multiple experiments I ended up doing hacky JPQL query. Here is code-snippet:

```
List<Long> lstExistingVisitors = ...
Query qDeleteVisitors = em.createQuery("delete from Visitor obj where obj.id in (?1)");
qDeleteVisitors.setParameter(1, lstExistingVisitors);
qDeleteVisitors.executeUpdate();
```

I tried list as big as 5000 IDs. It works fine with mysql 5.1 and H2DB.

Comment: Using query to delete is much faster than remove-method, but this way you need to remove possible children manually. In other words: if performance requires it, use query, else remove by looping and calling remove.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use JPQL

```
em.createQuery("delete from  Visitor v where v.id in (:param)")
.setParameter("param", idsList).executeUpdate();
```

OpenJPA docs: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_bulk_ops

Comment: Unfortunately Query.executeUpdate() will send query to DB right away. It won't queue them until `em.commit()` I tested with mysql+openjpa.

Comment: em.commit ... ? Your transaction management is just werid. What's your platform? Don't you have any transaction manager? On the other hand even if it sends statement to DB, transaction still may be not commited, and you can rollback your changes. I can't se the problem here.

Comment: The problem is that it's too slow when I delete 1K rows. I don't want OpenJPA to make any round-trip calls to DB.